# ScrollViewer Scrolling Event

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

is there any way to catch the following Events for ScrollViewer

```
ScrollViewer.ScrollStarter="ScrollStarted"
ScrollViewer.ScrollCompleted="ScrollCompleted"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are no events like `ScrollStarted` or `ScrollEnded` in silverlight. But you may create a `Dependency Property` listening the Horizontal and Vertical `Offset`s and use this `Dependecy Property` to fire a custom event indicating whether whether user scrolls or not.

[This link](http://blog.weareon.net/scrollviewer-scroll-change-event-in-silverlight/) includes a sample;

Comment: Provided link is good, but is there any other simple way to do so?

Comment: @Faizan http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jlikness/archive/2010/05/18/making-the-scrollviewer-talk-in-silverlight-4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I Think You Should Try My Way

```
public static class ScrollViewerBinding
{
  #region VerticalOffset attached property

  /// <summary>
  /// Gets the vertical offset value
  /// </summary>
  public static double GetVerticalOffset(DependencyObject depObj)
  {
    return (double)depObj.GetValue(VerticalOffsetProperty);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Sets the vertical offset value
  /// </summary>
  public static void SetVerticalOffset(DependencyObject depObj, double value)
  {
    depObj.SetValue(VerticalOffsetProperty, value);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// VerticalOffset attached property
  /// </summary>
  public static readonly DependencyProperty VerticalOffsetProperty =
      DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("VerticalOffset", typeof(double),
      typeof(ScrollViewerBinding), 
    new PropertyMetadata(0.0, OnVerticalOffsetPropertyChanged));

  #endregion
}
```